# Getting zero length array on angular merge although original array is of 3 length with 3 elements

Tags: angularjs, arrays, performance, prototype

I have an array.

```
var arr=new Array(3);
var o1={name:vv},o2:{name1:{}}; // This is just dummy data.
Now var obj= angular.merge({},o1,o2);
```

produces result as

```
obj={
   name:[],
   name1:{}
}
```

My question is why array length is reduced to zero in merge. I am not able to understand this scenario.

Part B:

```
var arr1=[1,2,3,3];
console.log(arr1);
```

[image]
Question is : what is meaning of this : **proto** :Array[0] ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [angular.merge](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.merge) docs. I believe it talks about merging objects into objects, not arrays, if you read the first sentence:

**Deeply extends the destination object dst by copying own enumerable properties from the src object(s) to dst.**

Comment: In normal case, it do merge arrays...If array will have values then so issue in merging